# Scrambling MySql Cell Content For Export / Import

Tags: mysql

There is a production system which contains sensitive data hosted on a MySQL database. I would like to export this data as-is without modifying the original content, but with certain columns in the *copy* being scrambled or replaced with randomly generated content for security reasons because it will be moved to a comparatively insecure environment (e.g. Names, Addresses). This data would then be imported into a development environment for performance testing etc.

Are there any convenient tools out there which allow me to export / import tools, while obfuscating / scrambling columns which contain sensitive data?

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I dont think that there is a out-of-the-box solution for your task.

I would do it programticaly either on the dumped text file or if you need to change more and do that often you could write a script that reads from your production system, scrambles the values and stores them directly to your testenvironment.